# how to setup hybrid PoW+PoS or PoA private network (geth)

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, proof-of-stake, proof-of-work, proof-of-authority

I am aware about **PoW** and **PoA** setups of **ethereum** private networks but would like to know if anyone could help or point me the direction how to build a hybrid **PoW + PoS** or **PoW + PoA** ethereum based network.

Is this something that can be done out of the box or with little code manipulation of the official ethereum distribution?

Comment: May I know what's your use case here? why do you need such a hybrid consensus system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for **POW + POS** => Casper.

Ethereum is about to face is its upgrade to proof-of-stake consensus. This is called Casper. the best thing for you is start with this article

https://www.finder.com/ethereum-casper

For **POW + POA** ... I don't think it makes sense to make this.